# Hibernate Not retrieving the data

Tags: java, hibernate

Iam trying to build a sample application with JAXRS/Hibernate.

I have sample data in my database,but i could not retrieve it.Please verify my code and let me know where Iam making error.

**Entity class**

```
package org.cricket.cricketstats.data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Table(name="player_info")
@Entity
public class PlayerInfo {   


@Id
@Column(name="player_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long playerId;

@Column(name="player_name")
private String playerName;

@Column(name="player_role")
private String playerRole;

@Column(name="player_batting_style")
private String playerBattingStyle;

@Column(name="player_bowling_style")
private String playerBowlingStyle;

@Column(name="player_image")
private String playerImage;

@Column(name="player_profile_desc")
private String playerProfile;


public PlayerInfo(){

}

public PlayerInfo(long playerId, String playerName, String playerRole, String playerBattingStyle,
        String playerBowlingStyle, String playerImage, String playerProfile) {
    super();
    this.playerId = playerId;
    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.playerRole = playerRole;
    this.playerBattingStyle = playerBattingStyle;
    this.playerBowlingStyle = playerBowlingStyle;
    this.playerImage = playerImage;
    this.playerProfile = playerProfile;
}


public long getPlayerId() {
    return playerId;
}

public void setPlayerId(long playerId) {
    this.playerId = playerId;
}

public String getPlayerName() {
    return playerName;
}

public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
    this.playerName = playerName;
}

public String getPlayerRole() {
    return playerRole;
}

public void setPlayerRole(String playerRole) {
    this.playerRole = playerRole;
}

public String getPlayerBattingStyle() {
    return playerBattingStyle;
}

public void setPlayerBattingStyle(String playerBattingStyle) {
    this.playerBattingStyle = playerBattingStyle;
}

public String getPlayerBowlingStyle() {
    return playerBowlingStyle;
}

public void setPlayerBowlingStyle(String playerBowlingStyle) {
    this.playerBowlingStyle = playerBowlingStyle;
}

public String getPlayerImage() {
    return playerImage;
}

public void setPlayerImage(String playerImage) {
    this.playerImage = playerImage;
}

public String getPlayerProfile() {
    return playerProfile;
}

public void setPlayerProfile(String playerProfile) {
    this.playerProfile = playerProfile;
}

}
```

**Rest Resource**

package org.cricket.cricketstats.resources;

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.cricket.cricketstats.data.PlayerInfoDAO;
import org.cricket.cricketstats.model.PlayerInfoBean;

@Path("players")
public class CricketResources {

PlayerInfoBean playerInfoBean= new PlayerInfoBean();

 @GET
 @Path("{playerId}")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public PlayerInfoBean getPlayerDetails(@PathParam("playerId") long id) {
     PlayerInfoDAO dao= new PlayerInfoDAO();
     dao.getPlayerInfo();
     playerInfoBean.setPlayerId(id);
     return playerInfoBean;
 }


 }
```

**Config file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- Connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cricket</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property     name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Print executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- validate all database on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

    <!-- Annotated entity classes -->
    <mapping class="org.cricket.cricketstats.data.PlayerInfo"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**DAO class**

```
package org.cricket.cricketstats.data;
import java.util.List;

import org.cricket.cricketstats.model.PlayerInfoBean;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
public class PlayerInfoDAO {


public void getPlayerInfo(){
    Configuration config=new Configuration().configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry= new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
     //StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
    // SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
     SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);     
     Session session = factory.openSession();
     Transaction tx =session.beginTransaction();
    List infoList=session.createQuery("FROM PlayerInfo").list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println(infoList.get(0).getPlayerName());

}


}
```

**I have tried to give full path also in query **

Comment: WARN: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: FROM org.cricket.cricketstats.data.PlayerInfo
maj 10, 2016 6:49:48 EM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

Comment: You should use AnnotationConfiguration instead of Configuration

Comment: @ike3 `AnnotationConfiguration` is used with Hibernate 3 only :)

Comment: @saivinod Which version oh Hibernate you use?

Comment: @v.ladynev This is the dependency i have in maven


       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.0.Final</version>

Comment: @saivinod Do you have any exception in the log?

Comment: If you are using Hibernate 5 or greater, working with a SessionFactory (not an EntityManagerFactory), and willing/able to annotate your classes then I would ditch the Hibernate mapping file and use native bootstrapping described in section 3.1 here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native

Comment: However, your problem is that Hibernate is not recognizing that PlayerInfo is an entity class.  Either your `Configuration/ServiceRegistry` is not picking up the config file or the config file is not properly describing that there is an annotated class named `PlayerInfo`.  I have not worked enough with Hibernate mapping files to know which case it is.

Answer (score 0):

The way is used by you to building a session factory is not correct for Hibernate 5. It can be used only for Hibernate 4.

Use this instead

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```